# Why would this be 5-ethyl-6,6-dimethyl-3-heptene when in aplhabetical order it should bebe: 6,6-dimethyl-5-ethyl-3-heptene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> Name the following compound:
>
> [image]

Why would this be **5-ethyl-6,6-dimethyl-3-heptene** when in alphabetical order it should be **6,6-dimethyl-5-ethyl-3-heptene**?

Comment: Actually, since 1993, the correct name according to IUPAC recommendations is 5-ethyl-6,6-dimethylhept-3-ene.

Answer (score 3):

The prefixes di-, tri-, etc. are not considered when determining the alphabetical order of the substituents. So the order is actually determined like this:

> 5-**e**thyl-6,6-di**m**ethyl-3-heptene

You can read up on this matter when following this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry).